# ZSH: Command Not Found: rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, zsh

rails is installed... running `gem list rails` returns `rails (3.2.1)`.. however when i run a rails command such as `rails new testapp -T` i get `Command Not Found: rails`

I am using RVM which installed to `~/.rvm/.

In /bin/bash shell the command works fine, however in /bin/zsh it does not.

My .zshrc file is:

```
# Path to your oh-my-zsh configuration.
ZSH=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh

# Set name of the theme to load.
# Look in ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/
# Optionally, if you set this to "random", it'll load a random theme each
# time that oh-my-zsh is loaded.
ZSH_THEME="doubleend"

# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set to this to use case-sensitive completion
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Comment this out to disable weekly auto-update checks
# DISABLE_AUTO_UPDATE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable colors in ls
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want to disable autosetting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment following line if you want red dots to be displayed while waiting for completion
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Which plugins would you like to load? (plugins can be found in ~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/*)
# Custom plugins may be added to ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
plugins=(git rails textmate ruby)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

[[ -s "/volumes/MacintoshHD/users/mikedevita/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/volumes/MacintoshHD/users/mikedevita/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

# Customize to your needs...
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin/:/tools
```

Comment: Just did and it fixed the problem..

Comment: Sorry about that, I saw the answer load below after I hit send. Glad to see you have it fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the issue is as simple as ensuring that the source script for rvm:

```
[[ -s "/volumes/MacintoshHD/users/mikedevita/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/volumes/MacintoshHD/users/mikedevita/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

is the last line in your zshrc file should do the trick, just move the defintion of your path above that line, source the .zshrc and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly.. stupid mistake.. Ill approve once i can.

Answer (score 10):

you have to add this in ~/.zshrc

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Answer (score 0):

your `$PATH` probably doesn't include where rails is installed. Check its value under bash, and adjust as appropriate. You might also be able to append `:$PATH` to the end of your existing `PATH` assignment, and get it that way.

Comment: Since RVM manages this he should just source RVM after setting the PATH. But basically you have the right idea.